# Call a function that takes in a pointer to the current class from inside the class

Tags: c++

I am trying to call a method outside of the Entity class that takes in an entity pointer as a parameter, and I am getting this compiler error:

> C3861: 'PrintEntity': Identifier not found

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Entity {
public:
    int x, y;

    Entity() {
        this->x = 0;
        this->y = 0;
    }

    Entity(int x, int y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;

        PrintEntity(this);
    }

    int GetX() const {
        const Entity* e = this;
    }
}; 

void PrintEntity(Entity* e) {
    std::cout << e->x << ", " << e->y << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Entity e(5, 5);
}
```

(This isn't practical code, but more of a proof-of-concept exercise)

I understand that this error is occurring because I have not defined a prototype for PrintEntity, and so the Entity class does not recognize the PrintEntity() function when it is called in the Entity constructor, but when I define a prototype just before the Entity class declaration like this:

```
void PrintEntity(Entity* e);

class Entity {
    ...
}
```

I get these 5 errors:

```
C2182: 'PrintEntity': illegal use of type 'void'
C2065: 'Entity': undeclared identifier
C2065: 'e': undeclared identifier
C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
C2365: 'PrintEntity': redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'
```

My understanding of why these errors are occurring is that the PrintEntity() prototype does not recognize the Entity class, as it has not been defined yet.

So if I cannot write the prototype before the class definition because Entity has not been defined, and I cannot call the PrintEntity() method without prototyping it, how can I make this code work while still being able to call PrintEntity() inside of the Entity class?

Comment: You forward-declare the `Entity` class before the first declaration of `PrintEntity` as well: `class Entity;`

Comment: @user17732522 another way to solve this would be to separate the implementation of the class into a `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to forward declare `Entity` and `PrintEntity` before the `class` definition and implement `PrintEntity` after the class definition:

```
class Entity;

void PrintEntity(Entity*);

class Entity {
    // ...
};

void PrintEntity(Entity* e) {
    std::cout << e->x << ", " << e->y << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xxe3MqfT3)
(Note that `GetX` doesn't return an `int` as it promised to do. That must be fixed)

It does look like you would be better off creating a header file with a class definition without member function implementations though. You should move those to a `.cpp` file instead.